# Python: how to set a column of a QTableWidget to Display in Date Format

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

```
def fill_buchungen(self):
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    data = helper.select("Select buchungsid,datum,einnahme, ausgabe,buchungstext,belegnr,mwst from buchung") 
    for row , form in enumerate(data):
        row_position = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_position)  
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row,1, QDateEdit().setDisplayFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"))            
        for column , item in enumerate(form):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row , column , QTableWidgetItem(str(item)))
```

This is what I have so far. The second column shows a date plus a time. But I would like to have it only as Date 'dd.mm.yyyy'

[image]

Comment: In `for column , item in enumerate(form)`, what is the data type of `item`? A `str` or a `datetime`?

Comment: `if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):  >>> value = value.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")`. Be aware that this is a string, so if you try to sort the column by it, it will sort it incorrectly. You need to use `"%Y.%m.%d"` format to have a lexicographic string sorting also correctly sort dates

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `item` to be a `datetime` object, you can use the `strftime` method to specify the datetime string formatting, e.g:

```
for column , item in enumerate(form):
    date_str = d.strftime("%d.%m.%y")
    self.tableWidget.setItem(row , column , QTableWidgetItem(date_str))
```

Comment: yes indeed, this is the easiest solution. I have this now and it works:
            for column , item in enumerate(form):
                if column ==1:
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row , column , QTableWidgetItem(item.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")))
                else:
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row , column , QTableWidgetItem(str(item)))

Comment: muchos Gracias!

Comment: unfurtunately this only works on my computer with the date format d.m.y. on other computer with other date format it fails understandably.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding an edit cell but you are not modifying the string, a trivial solution is the one indicated in the other post, a better one would be to convert it to QDateTime and modify the displayText method of a delegate:

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

```py
def fill_buchungen(self):
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    data = helper.select(
        "Select buchungsid,datum,einnahme, ausgabe,buchungstext,belegnr,mwst from buchung"
    )
    for row, form in enumerate(data):
        row_position = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_position)
        for column, item in enumerate(form):
            table_item = QTableWidgetItem()
            if isinstance(item, datetime):
                item = QDateTime(item)
            table_item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, item)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, table_item)
```

```
class DateDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, value, locale):
        if isinstance(value, QDateTime):
            return locale.toString(value, "dd-MM-yyyy")
        return super().displayText(value, locale)
```

```
date_delegate = DateDelegate(self.tableWidget)
self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, date_delegate)
```

Comment: This unfurtunately also doesnt work because all data is coming out of the database in strings. So i have to find a way of converting the strings into local date format.